# error while calling another activity by clicking an imagebutton

Tags: android

I want an emergency help,
I want to go to another activity when I click “ffp” imagebutton , but every time I click that , I will get an error, what should I do, everything is ok except calling that button. if I should use the AsynchTask then how ?
My Layout XML files have no error I checked it several times. , I provide my LoginActivity and manifest below :

```
package com.aminmousavi.safetransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {


private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:safewsdl#loginuser";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "loginuser";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:safewsdl";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/WebServiceSOAP/webs.php";

SoapObject request;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
Object response;
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   EditText emailet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailet); 
                   EditText passet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passet);
                   request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    //SoapObject 
                     request.addProperty("email", emailet.getText().toString());
               request.addProperty("password", passet.getText().toString());           
                   envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);      
            httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try
            {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                response = envelope.getResponse();
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }   
    });

   TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
               //Switching to Register screen
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
   });

    ImageButton ffp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fingerp);
    ffp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
          public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
              startActivity(new Intent("com.aminmousavi.SecondActivity"));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("AppErorr", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
     });
   }
 }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aminmousavi.safetransaction"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.aminmousavi.safetransaction.LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login to your Account" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
              android:label="Register New Account">

    </activity>
    <!--  Entry for FiongerprintActivity.class -->
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
              android:label="Second Activity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the stack trace. Much of the time the stack trace includes key information to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: paste your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

instead of:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.aminmousavi.SecondActivity"));
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me :

> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
>   com.aminmousavi.SecondActivity.class));